# how to change next page using swipeview in android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, swipeview

am new to android.am doing simple aphabate app.in that app am using alphabetes letters.when swipe on the letter how it will move to next letter.please give me suggestions

thanks in advance

Comment: hi amarnath, please post some code snippet of what you tried.

Comment: am searching on swipe.am not yet tried but how to impliment swipe?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest u  to tak a look at the following Android Dev blog post about using ViewPager in the Android Compatibility Package to implement the swipe functionality you're looking for:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

The recommended approach is most likely to use a Fragment for the chat history and text input field as this will give you the most flexibility across devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: In this link he is showing listview item on swipe.

[image]

[image]

Check the complete code [here](http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/dynamic-swipe-view-in-android.html)