# how to create dynamic swipe screens in android?

Tags: android

I am not asking for code or anything, but I am learning android myself while making an app. And my app requires to use swiping gesture to move across multiple dynamic lists. So I am thinking I can spawn 3 listviews widgets initially, and show the middle one while hiding the other 2, so when the user swipe either left or right, I would have something right at the moment ready to show. Then whenever a transition is made, the 2 hidden listviews would have to update their data to be the new left listview and right listview. So these listviews have to be in circular order too, like 1 -> 2 -> 3 then back to 1 like that.

I need some general directions on how to do it, online reading material would be great too.

If it should not be done in the way I described, give me the standard way of doing something like that.

It would be awesome if there's a library that can help me out with this.

[image]

Comment: here is the link just refer my answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393799/how-to-change-next-page-using-swipeview-in-android/14394182#14394182

Comment: you should use viewPager widget.

Comment: you have catch the gesture listenert(left or right) and on the basis of it bind your view.This link will doing same http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/dynamic-swipe-view-in-android.html

Answer (score 6):

For swiping gesture you have to use view flipper.But be sure before using this,This requires fragments which is not supported in api level less than 10.

Below are the following listed links

1) http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html

2) http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

3)http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/

Let me know if are still facing any issue